How can I set the Secure and HttpOnly flags on cookies on Shopify?
I am working on a shopify website and i have been examining the security of it. I found several cookies without secure and HttpOnly flags set on them, they are not sensitive cookies but to have a better security it can helps. These cookies are likely from third-party apps on shopify and since i can't modify the website on server side i need to find a way to modify them, with an apps or maybe an option that i didn't see. I searched a lot and nobody talks about these flags on shopify.
I tried to find apps to modify but it is most GDPR apps and not really to personalize them.
It will helps for the mozilla observatory scan score since he asks to put the secure flag.
Here are the cookies : 
